# Xcode -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a1248d0 - How to fix?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, nsarray

before I show my Code, be patient, I´m new to stackoverflow and to ObjectiveC.

My problem occurs, when I try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.side.article.categories);

NSLog(@"%@",side_.article.categories);
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.side.article.categories];

if ([self.side.article.categories isEqualToString:@"4"]) {          //here
 [[IOLSession defaultSession] logEventWithType:IOLEventTypeView
 state:IOLViewAppeared
 category:@"art_meldungen-des-tages"
 comment:nil];}
```

What I tried is getting the value of categories from a JSON :

```
"articles": [{"id":xxx,"date":xxx,"lastChanged":xxx,"weblink": 
"xxx","annotation":"xxx","imageURL": "xxx",
"thumbnailurl": "xxx","categories": [3], ...
```

And now how i fetch them:

```
- (void)updateArticlesWithParsedContent:(NSDictionary *)parsedContent
{
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *existingArticlesFetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
existingArticlesFetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSArray *existingArticlesFetchResult = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:existingArticlesFetchRequest error:NULL];
NSMutableDictionary *existingArticles = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:existingArticlesFetchResult forKeys:[existingArticlesFetchResult valueForKey:@"articleID"]];

NSMutableSet *articlesInParsedContentSet = [NSMutableSet set];

NSArray *parsedArticles = [parsedContent objectForKey:@"articles"];
for (NSDictionary *parsedArticle in parsedArticles) {

    NSNumber *articleID = [parsedArticle objectForKey:@"id"];

    Article *article = [existingArticles objectForKey:articleID];


         if (!article) {
        article = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        article.articleID = articleID;
        [existingArticles setObject:article forKey:articleID];
    }

    [articlesInParsedContentSet addObject:article];

    NSDate *parsedLastChanged = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[parsedArticle objectForKey:@"lastChanged"] doubleValue]];

    if (!article.lastChanged || ([article.lastChanged compare:parsedLastChanged] == NSOrderedAscending)) {

        article.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[parsedArticle objectForKey:@"date"] doubleValue]];
        article.annotation = [parsedArticle objectForKey:@"annotation"];
        article.weblink = [self baselineURLStringAppendedWithString:[parsedArticle valueForKey:@"weblink"]];
        article.imageURL = [self baselineURLStringAppendedWithString:[parsedArticle valueForKey:@"imageURL"]];
        article.thumbnailURL = [self baselineURLStringAppendedWithString:[parsedArticle valueForKey:@"thumbnailURL"]];
  -->      article.categories=[parsedArticle objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

And my Articles.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Side;

@interface Article : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * annotation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * articleID; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastChanged;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * thumbnailURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * weblink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * hasBeenRead;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *sides;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *categories;
@end

@interface Article (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addSidesObject:(Side *)value;
- (void)removeSidesObject:(Side *)value;
- (void)addSides:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSides:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

UPDATE:
I did, what you told me, but it´s still not working.

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.side.article.categories); // it shows the value of categories

NSNumber *num = [self.side.article.categories objectAtIndex:0 ];
NSLog (@"%@", num); // it shows the value of categories

if ([[self.side.article.categories objectAtIndex:0 ]isEqualToString:@"4"]) {          //here
 [[IOLSession defaultSession] logEventWithType:IOLEventTypeView
 state:IOLViewAppeared
 category:@"art_meldungen-des-tages"
 comment:nil];}
```

I just get :  (lldb) EXT_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2 , Adress= 0x4)!

PS: I also changed  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *categories; to  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *categories; .

The Solution is:

```
    if ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.side.article.categories objectAtIndex:0]]  isEqual:@"4") {...
```

Comment: categories seems to hold array object. Try using objectAtIndex.

Comment: "categories": [3] try use objectAtIndex and number value not string value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The categories object is of type of array. So you need to fetch the object from array. The categories object is not of type `NSString`. You should use code as:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.side.article.categories objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: ok, i´ve been to dump to understand first, but this solved my problem :)
i did:
    if ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",             [self.side.article.categories objectAtIndex:0]] isEqual:@"4")     {...

Answer (score 0):

As @Unnati said, in your JSON the categories object is not a string. You have the wrong type for categories in your object "article" model.

Comment: I changed the type of categories to NSNumber, now i just get (lldb)
EXT_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2 , Adress= 0x4)

Comment: Categories is a NSArray, and [categories objectAtIndex[i]] return a NSInteger value not a NSString,  like @Huy Nghia said in comment.